# Unit testing a query to a CRM database with Nunit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, crm

I have the following method that I am trying to write unit tests for:

```
        public Entity GetContactByEmail(string email)
        {
            var queryExpression = new QueryExpression(CRMFieldNames.Contact.EntityName);

            queryExpression.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(CRMFieldNames.Contact.EmailAddress1);

            queryExpression.Criteria.AddCondition(CRMFieldNames.Contact.EmailAddress1, ConditionOperator.Equal, email);

            var entities = _crmExecutor.Execute(service => service.RetrieveMultiple(queryExpression));

            if (entities.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                return entities.Entities[0];
            }

            return entities.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

I have attempted the following unit test:

```
     [Test]
        public void GetContactByEmail_AnyCase_ReturnsEntity()
        {
            var email = "lorem@ipsum.com";
            var repository = CreateEmailSendRepository();
            var query = new QueryExpression("contact");
            var entityCollection = new EntityCollection();
            entityCollection.Entities.Add(new Entity());

            _crmExecutor.Execute(_organizationService => _organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query)).Returns(entityCollection);

            var result = repository.GetContactByEmail(email);
            Assert.IsInstanceOf<Entity>(result);
        }

        private EmailSendRepository CreateEmailSendRepository()
            => new EmailSendRepository(_crmExecutor);
```

It is failing on the conditional in the `GetContactByEmail` method saying that `entities` = null. Can someone please point me in the right direction of giving entities a value here?

Comment: Are you trying to write an integration test or a unit test? The code above looks very much like an integration test.

Comment: @Bizhan I'm just trying to unit test this one method

Comment: I'm afraid that method is not abstracted therefore it's not possible to test it without preparing a production-like environment beforehand. You may want to refactor it completely to decouple the functionality from the "actual" database.

Comment: You can remove statics and follow OOP/SOLID to refactor this and then use frameworks such as Moq to write a unit test or you may setup everything that is done in production (creating a connection string and a database, filling it with test data, etc.) and call this test an integration/automation/functional test but definitely not a unit test.

Comment: Thanks @Bizhan - is there no other way to check that the method returns an Entity type?

Comment: sorry I just noticed that you are mocking `_crmExecutor.Execute`. The problem is you didn't initialize `entityCollection.Entities`

Comment: No problem, thanks @Bizhan - what do you mean by this? I need to do something like: 

`entityCollection.Entities.Returns...` ?

Comment: You don't need to mock the collection. you are already creating it inside the test method. something like `entityCollection.Entities = ...`

Comment: @Bizhan That results in the error that 'entityCollection.Entities' cannot be assigned to as it's read only. Please can you expand on your answer?

Comment: That was the most important part of the question that was missed until now. so EntityCollection is a built-in type without the possibility to be fabricated. in this case I don't see any reason to test `Execute` method. You may want to test "after" execute by converting the entityCollection to something that you can fabricate.